# Unable to asynchronously iterate over an array with asynchronous block using async.each()

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have some asynchronous functionality that I want to execute for each of the elements in the array `currencyData` as shown below. I have the following logic -

```
exports.getCurrenciesOfMerchant(req,res,function(currencyData)
{
     async.each(currencyData, function (eachCurrency) {
        fieldObject.currencyId=eachCurrency;
        console.log("See currencyData "+fieldObject.currencyId);

//async block starts here   
        couponHandler.checkIFWalletExists(res,fieldObject,function(fieldObject)
        {
            console.log("checked wallet for curr "+fieldObject.currencyId);
            if(fieldObject.hasWallet == 0)
            {
                exports.createWalletForUser(fieldObject,res,function(fieldObject,res){
//                        exports.createCoupon(fieldObject,res,function(res,fieldObject,couponId){
//                            return exports.couponCreationResponse(res,fieldObject,couponId);
//                        });
                    console.log("created wallet");
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Following is the output -

```
See currencyData 5
See currencyData 6
checked wallet for curr 6
checked wallet for curr 6
created wallet
created wallet
```

As can be seen, the async.each() took the value 6 before the asnychronous block completed execution. It never actually ran the logic for value 5.

I thought this is where async.each() would be useful. But, I could not make it work. Tried using `async.forEachOf` but got same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling the provided "done"-callback, so `async` doesn't know that the asynchronous operation has completed and won't continue processing the rest of the items. Change the iterator to

```
async.each(currencyData, function (eachCurrency, done) {
```

and call the `done`-function in your innermost callback.

```
exports.createCoupon(fieldObject,res,function(res,fieldObject,couponId){
    var res = exports.couponCreationResponse(res,fieldObject,couponId);
    done();
    return res;
});
```

**Edit:** ...and also in the else-branch of your if-conditional there, of course.

```
} else {
   done();
}
```

If you don't want the items to be processed concurrently, use [async.eachLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) instead:

```
async.eachLimit(currencyData, 1, function (eachCurrency, done) {
```

Comment: .each() with the done callback also did not work for me. Produced same results. However, eachLimit worked.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) says:

> Applies the function iteratee to each item in coll, in parallel. The
>   iteratee is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when
>   it has finished. If the iteratee passes an error to its callback, the
>   main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the
>   error.
>
> Note, that since this function applies iteratee to each item in
>   parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will
>   complete in order.

I suppose the method `couponHandler.checkIFWalletExists` is not commented out in your code. It means that the iterator will start processing second item before it finishes the processing of the first one. And probably because second item gets processed faster you see results in wrong order.

Comment: Yes that method was commented out by mistake. Ok, I don't mind parallel execution, but how do I ensure that the block executes for each value in the array `currencyData`? Should I use any other utility of the async library?

Comment: @SandeepanNath the method does execute for every item. You just override property of shared `fieldObject` for each item that's why you always see latest processed `fieldObject.currencyId`.